# when i compile this code it always 'sendCommand' was not declare in this scope..plzz help

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, softwareserial

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define DEBUG true

SoftwareSerial esp8266(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup() { // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600); //for monitoring purposes

  sendCommand("AT+CIFS+RST\r\n", 2000, DEBUG); // reset module
  sendCommand("AT+IPR=115200\r\n", 1000, DEBUG);
  sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); // configure as access point
  sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\"ABCDEFG\",\"12345678\"\r\n", 3000, DEBUG); //connect to a network with name ABCDEFG with password 12345678
  delay(1000);
  sendCommand("AT+CIFSR\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); // get ip address
  sendCommand("AT+CIPSTA=\"192.168.43.16\"\r\n", 1000, DEBUG);
  sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); // configure for multiple connections
  sendCommand("AT+CIPSERVER=1,6625\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); // turn on server on port 6625
  Serial.println("Server Ready");

}

void loop() { // run over and over
  if (esp8266.available()) {
    if (esp8266.find("+IPD,0,")) {
      delay(10);
      esp8266.find(":");
      delay(10);
      char letter = esp8266.read();
      Serial.print(letter); //for monitoring purposes
      //Gets the value/char from android app
    }


String sendCommand(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug) {
  String response = "";
  esp8266.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266
  long int time = millis();
  while ((time + timeout) > millis()) {
    while (esp8266.available()) {
      // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window
      char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
      response += c;
    }
  }

  if (debug) {
    Serial.print(response);
  }
  return response;
}
```

Comment: I formatted your code and now you can see two } missing to close the loop. (and misplaced comment). and I added `char` before `letter`

Comment: sir..i add change the code but still, i cant compile it, it still says 'sendCommand' was not declared in this scope..

Comment: Then edit your question to reflect the new code, so that we can help you

Comment: You did notice that you declared and defined `SendCommand()` *inside* `loop()`, right?

Comment: sir sorry for being slow..
what loop() do you mean sir?

Comment: there is only one loop()

Answer (score 2):

In `loop` you have three opening braces and one closing brace. This won't end well:

```
void loop() { // run over and over
  if (esp8266.available()) {
    if (esp8266.find("+IPD,0,")) {
      delay(10);
      esp8266.find(":");
      delay(10);
      char letter = esp8266.read();
      Serial.print(letter); //for monitoring purposes
      //Gets the value/char from android app
    }
```

Two more closing braces would fix it.

Comment: tnx sir..i can upload it now..
sory again sir...can i ask again sir..

i can upload it now but when use at command in serial monitor, no words is going out,,